# Docker images are not updated

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I want to build an image and run a container, but after some changes in code I rebuild image and run container using this command `docker-compose up --build`.
But in Docker Desktop in the list of images I see `Created about 6 hours ago.` But I did it 2 minutes ago.
I regularly delete images in docker desktop before rebuilding, but I see that behavior is not changing.
The only way out is to completely reinstall docker desktop application after 3-5 rebuilt images, but it's insane!
What's the problem? Is it some cache?
This is my docker-compose

```
    version: '3'
services:
  attachment-loader-prim:
    container_name: attachment-loader
    build:
      context: ""
    restart: always
    image: attachment-loader:latest
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "prim"
      LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL: DEBUG
      LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SQL_BASICBINDER: TRACE
    networks:
      - loader-network
    ports:
      - 8005:8005
      - 8085:8085
      
  attachment-loader-sec:
    container_name: attachment-loader-sec
    build:
      context: ""
    restart: always
    image: attachment-loader:latest
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "sec"
      LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL: DEBUG
      LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SQL_BASICBINDER: TRACE
    networks:
      - loader-network
    ports:
      - 8006:8005
      - 8086:8086

networks:
  loader-network:
    attachable: true
```

This is my dockerfile

```
    FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
VOLUME /tmp
ARG TZ='Europe/Berlin'

RUN sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/uk.alpinelinux.org/' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk upgrade --update \
    && apk add -U tzdata curl jq \
    && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime \
    && apk del tzdata \
    && rm -rf \
    /var/cache/apk/*
RUN echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone

ARG DEPENDENCY=build/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8005","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.path.to.your.Application.kt"]
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. I have this problem if I forget the `--build` flag. I never had this behaviour when I included the `--build` flag.

Comment: So start with clean docker instance and build your image once. Try `docker image ls` then change your code and build it second time and then compare old output from `docker image ls` with new one. Are there both images or only one?

Comment: @DevilaN I did that, and after changing code and rebuild I see the same images with field 'Created: 25 minutes ago', though I've built new images minute ago

Comment: Please include the output of your build command. We need to see that the build is successful and not cached.

Answer (score 1):

After `docker-compose build --no-cache` To make sure it restarts with the most updated image I use:

`docker-compose up -d <service> --force-recreate`

Answer (score 0):

To force a build with no cache, you could try using the `--no-cache` option which will rule out any caching option from actually happening. You could also force clean-up all the images by using something along these lines

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

and then try the rebuild again.

Without more details or seeing the actual docker-compose file being used, this is a general attempt to resolve the issue.

EDIT: Based on the example you are showing, it may not pick up any changes in the dockerfile for the new image that would be built, which a --build would then just use the cached image that was built earlier. If you have the output of the build that would be helpful, but if there is no reason for docker to build a new image, it will skip in favor of the cache image that already exists. Try the --no-cache option in the build and check all COPY/RUN args that you expect to trigger a new build actually will.

Comment: Seems like this command does the same as manual deletion of images in Docker Desktop. For now seems that behavior is the same, sometimes images update, sometimes not. My colleague heard, that Docker Desktop has some internal cache, or database, where it stores built images. But I didn't investigate this question yet.