# Docker Images are not updated with `docker build` when there is a file change or WORKDIR variable change

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

My docker file is rather lengthy. But to illustrate the problem I will post the following which gives me a similar behaviour.

```
################# Pulling Pre-Built Tensorflow Image ####################

ARG REGION=us-east-1
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:2.10.0-gpu-py39-cu112-ubuntu20.04-ec2

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE

COPY packages/xbox_pkg/ /opt/packages/xbox_pkg/
WORKDIR /opt/packages/xbox_pkg/
RUN python setup.py build && python setup.py install


######################### Install Python Code ###########################

COPY game_module/requirements.txt /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --requirement /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY game_module/code/ /opt/ml/code/
### TEST-1
WORKDIR /opt/ml/code/
### TEST-2
#WORKDIR /opt/ml/


########################### SageMaker section ################################

# The directory within the container in which the Python script for training is located.
ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/code

# The Python script that should be invoked and used as the entry point for training.
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM xbox_main.py
```

**Problem 1.1** : The expected behaviour is when you change WORKDIR from TEST_1 to TEST_2 and run  `docker build -t xbox_main . -f Dockerfile --build-arg REGION=us-east-1 --progress=plain` the last 3 simple layers to be rebuilt and create an updated image. And its run with `docker run -it $(AWS_ID).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/catalyst` do open a shell at `/opt/ml/` instead of previous `/opt/ml/code` This does not happen.

**Problem 1.2** : Then I made a code change, inserted a brand new source file inside `game_module` folder. This file was also not available in the container.

**Problem 2** :Then I thought may be this is some container caching detail which is not known to me. So still if I push the image to my repo, docker will push new layers instead of saying **Already Exists** for all layers. When pushing to repository clearly after all those changes, no indication whatsoever that updated layers are being pushed.

I ran docker run with container and the changes were still not reflected.

I came across this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996204/docker-images-are-not-updated) discussing the same kind of problem with no accepted answer. But given answers points to build option `--no-cache`. I doubt this is what I need as this would mean rebuilding the whole image which takes a load of time.

Are all these known issues? What kind of solutions instead of rebuilding and repushing I can try? (The entire image is about 6 GB)

**Related Question 1** : When pushing AWS ECR, does Docker check layer hashes and push only the updated layers?

**Related Question 2** : Is it possible to commit changes to docker image in ECR without pulling to local machine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer one of your questions

---

**Problem 1.1**

I think you have some misconceptions on what `WORKDIR` actually does. To quote [the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir):

> The `WORKDIR` instruction sets the working directory for any `RUN`,
> `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, `COPY` and `ADD` instructions that follow it in
> the Dockerfile.

None of these commands follow the setting of the `WORKDIR` so this is working as intended.

---

**EDIT**
So, it seems that `WORKDIR` does not add a layer, it only adds metadata to the Image Config.

See [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/docker-workdir-instruction/) for reference

Comment: When I delete the previously built image and create a new one and add WORKDIR as the last instruction whichever the Directory I set is where the interactive terminal's working directory. So I don't think WORKDIR is working as intended in my case.

Comment: see my updated answer, but `WORKDIR` does not add a new layer...

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I spent so much time reading docs about layers and didn't think to check this. Much appreciated!